# SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

Tags: javascript, heroku

When launching code in Heroku, I always get an unexpected token } error. Locally, it all works. 
Here is the code I used. This is an example from the discord.io repo. I have installed discord.io and made sure that node and npm were the same version as what I was running on my local machine.

```
var Discord = require('discord.io');
var logger = require('winston');
var auth = require('./auth.json');
// Configure logger settings
//logger.remove(logger.transports.Console);
 //logger.add(logger.transports.Console, {
colorize: true
});
 //logger.level = 'debug';
 // Initialize Discord Bot
var bot = new Discord.Client({
token: auth.token,
autorun: true
});
bot.on('ready', function (evt) {

});
bot.on('message', function (user, userID, channelID, message, evt) {
// Our bot needs to know if it will execute a command
// It will listen for messages that will start with `!`
if (message.substring(0, 1) == '!') {
    var args = message.substring(1).split(' ');
    var cmd = args[0];

    args = args.splice(1);
    switch(cmd) {
        // !ping
        case 'ping':
            bot.sendMessage({
                to: channelID,
                message: 'Pong!'
            });
        break;
        // Just add any case commands if you want to..
     }
 }
});
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: The `colorize: true });` part is pretty much invalid syntax. It's probably different in your local file, so it works there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//logger.add(logger.transports.Console, {
    colorize: true
});
```

Should be:

```
//logger.add(logger.transports.Console, {
    //colorize: true
//});
```

Or:

```
logger.add(logger.transports.Console, {
    colorize: true
});
```

Depending on whether you want it commented or not.

Comment: Thank you so much. I commented out all the logger lines but didnt comment the brace... Thats what caused the issue. Locally the logger wasnt commented out. Thanks for the help!!!!